# How to read Following out put in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
{"GetFundListResult":"[{\"Fcode\":\"F0075\",\"name\":\"Axis Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0003\",\"name\":\"Birla Sunlife Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0007\",\"name\":\"DSP BlackRock Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0032\",\"name\":\"Franklin Templeton Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0014\",\"name\":\"HDFC Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0025\",\"name\":\"ICICI Prudential Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0013\",\"name\":\"IDFC Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0020\",\"name\":\"Kotak Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0006\",\"name\":\"L\\u0026T Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0065\",\"name\":\"Mirae Asset Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0026\",\"name\":\"Reliance Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0027\",\"name\":\"SBI Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0029\",\"name\":\"Sundaram Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0030\",\"name\":\"Tata Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0034\",\"name\":\"UTI Mutual Fund\"}]"}
```

Comment: That's json data. Something like: `json_obj = JSON.parse(jsondata);`

Comment: Your probably better off asking this over at StackOverflow.

Comment: You need to provide more context. It's unclear in which form you have this data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {"GetFundListResult":"[{\"Fcode\":\"F0075\",\"name\":\"Axis Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0003\",\"name\":\"Birla Sunlife Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0007\",\"name\":\"DSP BlackRock Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0032\",\"name\":\"Franklin Templeton Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0014\",\"name\":\"HDFC Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0025\",\"name\":\"ICICI Prudential Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0013\",\"name\":\"IDFC Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0020\",\"name\":\"Kotak Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0006\",\"name\":\"L\\u0026T Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0065\",\"name\":\"Mirae Asset Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0026\",\"name\":\"Reliance Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0027\",\"name\":\"SBI Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0029\",\"name\":\"Sundaram Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0030\",\"name\":\"Tata Mutual Fund\"},{\"Fcode\":\"F0034\",\"name\":\"UTI Mutual Fund\"}]"};
var jsondata = JSON.parse(data['GetFundListResult']);
```

This should do the trick

Comment: It's `JSON`, not `Json`. What makes you think what the OP posted is a JavaScript object assigned to `data`?

Comment: Used an arbitrary data object. I had no idea what OP called it. There's not much context but hopefully OP can deduce that I was using an arbitrary name. It doesn't seem too crazy that OP would receive such an object. As a contrived example, i know localStorage generally returns string representations of Javascript objects